# How to Develop App Like, Lock app(Touch Id) in iOS?

Tags: swift

**I want to develop a universal App lock(Touch ID) in iOS and lock(Touch ID) should apply to another app. Is it possible to develop like this app in iOS by using a swift language.**

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible in iOS to access information about other apps. Apple’s major concern is security so it doesn’t allow app to access other apps. Your app could not access the things out if its box.